# How to normalize prediction data in a 2nd testing dataset with sigma/mu used in training?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a model that I am using with two datasets, Training & Testing. I need to normalize the predictors prior to building a model using scikit-learn.

Lets say for my model training data:

```
   Training[X1] has mean=10,stddev=1.5
   Training[X2] has mean=45,stddev=17
   etc...
```

And my for test data file

```
   Testing[X1] has mean=9,stddev=1.8
   Testing[X2] has mean=40,stddev=13
   etc...
```

How do I normalize the test data file so that it's using the same scale as the original dataset?

I attempted using this code, but it doesn't seem to look right at first glance:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
scaler = StandardScaler()  
scaler.fit(X_train)  
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)  
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code presented is the correct approach, you fit mean/std during training and later on just use it during test phase. The fact that mu/sigma between train and test are different is normal, and you have to deal with it. The only reason of such situation is too small dataset, given enough data points these two values would converge (assuming that data is correctly collected).

Comment: Correct, my test dataset (less than 1k records) is quite small compared to the training set (65k records).  Thanks for the confirmation, I'll have to look into the model more closely to see if something else is awry then.